# Slowly print text in Java

Tags: java

I just got started with Java programming, and I'm trying to print a string of text, one character after another, with a delay. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class SlowPrintHello {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Get message, convert to char array
        String message = "Hello, World!";
        char[] chars = message.toCharArray();

        // Print a char from the array, then sleep for 1/10 second
        for (int i = 0; i == chars.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(chars[i]);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        // Repeat for all chars
    }

}
```

When I run in Eclipse, the console says terminated without any output. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You can use a debugger and check how the code behaves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The problem:**

```
for (int i = 0; i == chars.length; i++)
```

it should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
```

It will always return `false`, thus breaking your `for` loop without iterating inside of it

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks a lot!