# Creating a custom method to slowly print text in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to create a method in Java that will accept a string to slowly print out. I found the code to do a slow print on here([Slowly print text in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333935/slowly-print-text-in-java)), and have been trying to make a method out of it, but I'm still very new to Java. Here's my code

```
public class propago
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String strMessage;  
        strMessage = "Testing 1 2 3";
        slowPrint(strMessage);
    }//end main(String[])

    public static void slowPrint(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        char[] chars = strMessage.toCharArrray();

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(chars[i]);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }//end slowPrint(String[])
}//end propago
```

The answer might be obvious, but I'm just not getting it.

When trying to compile the code, I get the following errors:

```
propago.java:12: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]

                slowPrint(strMessage);
                          ^
propago.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                char[] chars = strMessage.toCharArrray();
                               ^
  symbol:   variable strMessage
  location: class propago
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
2 errors
```

After applying the suggested changes (hopefully correctly), incompatible types error was solved, but I still receive the following error

```
propago.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                char[] chars = strMessage.toCharArray();
                               ^
  symbol:   variable strMessage
  location: class propago
1 error
```

Here is my current code with changes made

```
public class propago
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String strMessage;  
        strMessage = "Testing 1 2 3";
        slowPrint(strMessage);
    }//end main(String[])

    public static void slowPrint(String args)
    {
        char[] chars = strMessage.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(chars[i]);
            try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                //Should not happen
            }
        }
    }//end slowPrint(String[])
}//end propago
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does it work? Does it show some error if you run it? Does it show an error if you compile it? Please [edit] your question to add the details about what is wrong. It helps a lot if you show what is wrong.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting to add something to my question, thank you

Comment: Why do you want to accept array of strings when you are using it as single string? Remove those `[]` from `slowPrint(String[] args)`.

Comment: Also argument of `slowPrint` is named as `args` not `strMessage`. Those are separate variables and they belong to different code blocks.

Comment: Related (I am not marking it as duplicate since I am not sure if you want to know reasons behind errors or just get working solution): [making text appear delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19882885)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct the following:

- `slowPrint` method should take a `String` instead of a `String[]`
- Use `args` parameter in `slowPrint` method
- Method `toCharArrray` is not valid. Change to `toCharArray` instead
- Catch the `InterruptedException` exception when calling `slowPrint` method

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that, I've just begun learning Java at my university this semester and I assume for what we are currently covering, we haven't needed to worry about the difference between using "String" and "String[]". Now I just have the following error: 
```
propago.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                char[] chars = strMessage.toCharArray();
                               ^
  symbol:   variable strMessage
  location: class propago
```

Comment: See my second item on the list, you are trying to use `strMessage` which is not declared anywhere in `slowPrint` scope. Change it to `args` which is the parameter you are passing to this method.

Comment: Oh! Thank you, I wasn't even thinking to change "strMessage.toCharArray()" to be "args.toCharArray()". It's working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `slowPrint` that it takes a `String` array and may throw an unchecked Exception, namely `InterruptedException`.

To solve the problem with the `String` array, just change the method to take a `String`, not `String[]`

In your code there is no reason to believe someone will interrupt your code (only happens in multi-threaded code), so you may just ignore it by catching the exception when it occurs:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    return;
}
```

Then remove the `throws InterruptedException` from the declaration of `slowPrint`.

Comment: Recommend `catch (InterruptedException e) { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); break; }`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class propago
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String strMessage;  
        strMessage = "Testing 1 2 3";
        slowPrint(strMessage);
    }//end main(String[])

    public static void slowPrint()
    {
        char[] chars = this.strMessage.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(chars[i]);
            try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                //Should not happen
            }
        }
    }//end slowPrint(String[])
}//end propago
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little beyond the needed answer, but I wanted to define how I would approach it: having a thread-safe receiver for your calls. This could then queue up the messages in an appropriate delay in another thread:

```
public class MyLogger {

    private final Logger logger; //some logger
    private final Deque<String> out = new ArrayDeque();
    private final long msgDelayMS; //how long of a time must exist between messages

    public MyLogger(long msgDelayMS) {
        this.msgDelayMS = msgDelayMS;
    }

    public void log(String simpleString) {
        //Use a ReadWriteLock on `out` or somesuch to synchronize the data safely
        this.out.add(simpleString);
    }

    public ScheduledFuture<?> start(ScheduledExecutorService executor) {
        return executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::printNext, 0, this.msgDelayMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private void printNext() {
        //again, synchronize with a `lock` field or somesuch
        String next = this.out.poll();
        if (next == null) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(next); //prints however we like our valid queue'd item
    }
}
```

I didn't want to bog down into the multithreading details too much, but in this you essentially have a thread-safe wrapper for any form of logging you wanted to do. Then using it is just:

```
MyLogger logger = new MyLogger(1000L); //1000ms delay == 1 second
logger.start(Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()); //should keep the executor somewhere
//elsewheres, from any thread, without having to keep track of time or sleep the thread
logger.log("Hello world!");
```

This separates the "execution" of your logging and your actual program logic. So things may be logged that happened 30 seconds in the past, if you logged 30 messages within a specific moment. But it does make your logging non-blocking, in the sense that you don't have to wait for it to be an appropriate time to print, you just set it aside for another thread to handle. I suppose this answer is to kind of entice a little programming spirit, and also because I was kind of toying with a similar idea in my head at the moment anyhow.